# Merge Two Lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists

```
first = list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
second = list(a = 2, b = 3, c = 4)
```

I want to merge these two lists so the final product is

```
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 2 3

$c
[1] 3 4
```

Is there a simple function to do this?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349608/merge-contents-within-list-of-list-by-duplicate-name

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992657/how-to-merge-two-lists-based-on-object-indices

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If lists always have the same structure, as in the example, then a simpler solution is

```
mapply(c, first, second, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `Map(c, first, second)`, if anyone cares.

Comment: I'm just learning R, why does Map (and mapply) have 'c' as the first parameter?  Shouldn't the parameters passed in simply be the two lists?

Comment: 'c' is the name of a primitive function that creates lists.  Typing c in R without the trailing parens shows 'function (..., recursive = FALSE)  .Primitive("c")'  So this cliche is mapping the 'c' function over the contents of first and second.

Comment: @Masterfool mapply() is a tick more efficient, since `Map()` contains `mapply()`

Comment: how seriously do we need to worry about the following mapply warning: 'longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter'

Comment: list <- mapply(c, first, second, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)   The created list has two elements in each list element. How do I get in the given example list$a = 12 instead of list$a = 1 2 etc.? So that length(list$a) = 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 26):

This is a very simple adaptation of the modifyList function by Sarkar. Because it is recursive, it will handle more complex situations than `mapply` would, and it will handle mismatched name situations by ignoring the items in 'second' that are not in 'first'.

```
appendList <- function (x, val) 
{
    stopifnot(is.list(x), is.list(val))
    xnames <- names(x)
    for (v in names(val)) {
        x[[v]] <- if (v %in% xnames && is.list(x[[v]]) && is.list(val[[v]])) 
            appendList(x[[v]], val[[v]])
        else c(x[[v]], val[[v]])
    }
    x
}

> appendList(first,second)
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 2 3

$c
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: This is the one that helped me with a more complicated list. The other options didn't seem to handle elements under other elements.

Comment: Yes. IIRC that was the beauty of Sarkar's original that I appreciated and sought to give proper credit.

Answer (score 12):

Here are two options, the first:

```
both <- list(first, second)
n <- unique(unlist(lapply(both, names)))
names(n) <- n
lapply(n, function(ni) unlist(lapply(both, `[[`, ni)))
```

and the second, which works only if they have the same structure:

```
apply(cbind(first, second),1,function(x) unname(unlist(x)))
```

Both give the desired result.

Comment: I don't think your second one works correctly as I get a matrix design instead of a list of vectors.

Comment: You are right; `apply` simplifies it if it can.  It does work if it can't simplify, such as if `first$c <- c(4,5)`, for example.

Comment: the first one gives me a list of length=0. is names supposed to be defined as something?

Comment: do your lists have names?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that I ended up writing, based upon @Andrei's answer but without the elegancy/simplicity. The advantage is that it allows a more complex recursive merge and also differs between elements that should be connected with `rbind` and those that are just connected with `c`:

```
# Decided to move this outside the mapply, not sure this is 
# that important for speed but I imagine redefining the function
# might be somewhat time-consuming
mergeLists_internal <- function(o_element, n_element){
  if (is.list(n_element)){
    # Fill in non-existant element with NA elements
    if (length(n_element) != length(o_element)){
      n_unique <- names(n_element)[! names(n_element) %in% names(o_element)]
      if (length(n_unique) > 0){
        for (n in n_unique){
          if (is.matrix(n_element[[n]])){
            o_element[[n]] <- matrix(NA, 
                                     nrow=nrow(n_element[[n]]), 
                                     ncol=ncol(n_element[[n]]))
          }else{
            o_element[[n]] <- rep(NA, 
                                  times=length(n_element[[n]]))
          }
        }
      }

      o_unique <- names(o_element)[! names(o_element) %in% names(n_element)]
      if (length(o_unique) > 0){
        for (n in o_unique){
          if (is.matrix(n_element[[n]])){
            n_element[[n]] <- matrix(NA, 
                                     nrow=nrow(o_element[[n]]), 
                                     ncol=ncol(o_element[[n]]))
          }else{
            n_element[[n]] <- rep(NA, 
                                  times=length(o_element[[n]]))
          }
        }
      }
    }  

    # Now merge the two lists
    return(mergeLists(o_element, 
                      n_element))

  }
  if(length(n_element)>1){
    new_cols <- ifelse(is.matrix(n_element), ncol(n_element), length(n_element))
    old_cols <- ifelse(is.matrix(o_element), ncol(o_element), length(o_element))
    if (new_cols != old_cols)
      stop("Your length doesn't match on the elements,",
           " new element (", new_cols , ") !=",
           " old element (", old_cols , ")")
  }

  return(rbind(o_element, 
               n_element, 
               deparse.level=0))
  return(c(o_element, 
           n_element))
}
mergeLists <- function(old, new){
  if (is.null(old))
    return (new)

  m <- mapply(mergeLists_internal, old, new, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
  return(m)
}
```

Here's my example:

```
v1 <- list("a"=c(1,2), b="test 1", sublist=list(one=20:21, two=21:22))
v2 <- list("a"=c(3,4), b="test 2", sublist=list(one=10:11, two=11:12, three=1:2))
mergeLists(v1, v2)
```

This results in:

```
$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

$b
[1] "test 1" "test 2"

$sublist
$sublist$one
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   20   21
[2,]   10   11

$sublist$two
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   21   22
[2,]   11   12

$sublist$three
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2
```

Yeah, I know - perhaps not the most logical merge but I have a complex parallel loop that I had to generate a more customized `.combine` function for, and therefore I wrote this monster :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
merged = map(names(first), ~c(first[[.x]], second[[.x]])
merged = set_names(merged, names(first))
```

Using purrr. Also solves the problem of your lists not being in order.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a `lapply` with `c()`, and use `setNames` to assign the original name to the output.

```
setNames(lapply(1:length(first), function(x) c(first[[x]], second[[x]])), names(first))

$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 2 3

$c
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In general one could,

```
merge_list <- function(...) by(v<-unlist(c(...)),names(v),base::c)
```

Note that the `by()` solution returns an `attribute`d list, so it will print differently, but will still be a list. But you can get rid of the attributes with `attr(x,"_attribute.name_")<-NULL`. You can probably also use `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Aaron left Stack Overflow and @Theo answer, the merged list's elements are in form of vector `c`.
But if you want to bind rows and columns use `rbind` and `cbind`.

```
merged = map(names(first), ~rbind(first[[.x]], second[[.x]])
merged = set_names(merged, names(first))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, I found that this line works for named lists using the same names:

```
as.list(bind_rows(first, second))
```