# How to merge lists with identical column names to get their union

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

Say I have N lists that all have the same column names. I want to merge these such that I get a resulting list with same columns, but now containing entries from all N list. Here is a MWE showing what I want:

```
  ls<-list()
ls[[1]]<-list("a"=1,
              "b"=2)
    ls[[2]]<-list("a"=3,
                  "b"=4)

#how to write a one-liner that produces lsTotal, which is the union of ls[[1]] and ls[[2]]?

lsTotal<-list("a"=c(1,3),
              "b"=c(2,4))
```

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519543/merge-two-lists-in-r), from which I can use `Map(c, ls[[1]], ls[[2]])`. However, writing it out is tedious if `ls` is very long. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: Note that it's less typing to build your example list in one line: `ls <- list(list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4))`.

Comment: Are the elements in the sublists always in the same order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
transpose(ls) %>%
        map(unlist)
```

---

Or use `Map` with `do.call`

```
do.call(Map, c(f=c, ls))
#$a
#[1] 1 3

#$b
#[1] 2 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple two-liner with `unlist` and `split`.

```
# get a named vector
tmp <- unlist(ls)

# split on the names
split(unname(tmp), names(tmp))
$a
[1] 1 3

$b
[1] 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has a few answers but another option is to use `Reduce` with your `Map` to apply the `Map` to each of the elements successively in the list:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) Map(c,x,y), ls)
#$a
#[1] 1 3

#$b
#[1] 2 4
```

Or for a more complicated example, the results are:

```
ls <- list(list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4), list(a=2,b=4), list(a=5,b=2), list(a=3,b=2))

#$a
#[1] 1 3 2 5 3

#$b
#[1] 2 4 4 2 2
```