# Merge list of list on sublist level

Tags: r, list, merge

I am given two list of lists. I would like to merge the list on the sublist Level. As an example, I am given

```
L1 <- list(list("a"=1,"b"=2),list("a"=10,"b"=20))
L2 <- list(list("c"=3,"d"=4),list("c"=5,"d"=6))
```

I would like to create a total list looking as follows:

```
Ltot<-list(list("a"=1,"b"=2,"c"=3,"d"=4),list("a"=10,"b"=20,"c"=5,"d"=6))
```

Comment: Related [Merge Two Lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519543/merge-two-lists-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map`, i.e.

```
Map(`c`, L1, L2)

identical(Map(`c`, L1, L2), Ltot)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the backtick on `c`? `Map(c, L1, L2)` works just as fine.

Comment: @nicola I guess it's a habit of mine when using such functions (`Map`, `Reduce`, etc) and do not specify `Map(function(i)c(i), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(L1, L2, c)
```