# Merge List containing Lists with the same structure

Tags: r, mapply

I have a list containing multiple lists which all have the same structure:

```
ls <- list(
one = list(df = data.frame(var1_1 = c(1, 1, 1),
                           var1_2 = c('a', 'a', 'a')),
           ls = list(n_df_1 = data.frame(var3_1 = c('x', 'x', 'x'),
                                         var3_2 = c(4, 4, 4))),
           name = c("one", "one", "one")),
two = list(df = data.frame(var1_1 = c(1, 1, 1),
                           var1_2 = c('a', 'a', 'a')),
           ls = list(n_df_1 = data.frame(var3_1 = c('x', 'x', 'x'),
                                         var3_2 = c(4, 4, 4))),
           name = c("two", "two", "two")))
```

I want to merge all these nested lists like stated here: [Merge Two Lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519543/merge-two-lists-in-r/44499941)

It does exactly what want if I do this:

```
merged <- mapply(c, ls[[1]], ls[[2]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

The problem is, is that the main list (ls) doesn't always have only two nested lists. How can I make this code more modular?

I tried to make a vector containing all indexes of the nested lists:

```
sapply(seq_along(ls), function(x) paste0("ls[[", x, "]]"))
```

Which output this:

```
[1] "ls[[1]]" "ls[[2]]"
```

I thought I could unquote these character vector so that R sees them as object. But I can't figure out how to do that (if it's even possible). I looked at tidy eval for this, but I'm don't know if this is the way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't name your list `ls`. There is a predefine function `ls` in R which you overwrite by redefining it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to do it on an abstract number of list elements, i.e.

```
Reduce(function(...)Map(c, ...), l1) #Map = mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $df
> $df$var1_1
> [1] 1 1 1
>
> $df$var1_2
> [1] a a a
> Levels: a
>
> $df$var1_1
> [1] 1 1 1
>
> $df$var1_2
> [1] a a a
> Levels: a
>
>
> $ls
> $ls$n_df_1
>   var3_1 var3_2
> 1      x      4
> 2      x      4
> 3      x      4
>
> $ls$n_df_1
>   var3_1 var3_2
> 1      x      4
> 2      x      4
> 3      x      4
>
>
> $name
> [1] "one" "one" "one" "two" "two" "two"
> ```

**DATA:**

```
dput(l1)
list(one = list(df = structure(list(var1_1 = c(1, 1, 1), var1_2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), ls = list(n_df_1 = structure(list(var3_1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), var3_2 = c(4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), name = c("one", "one", "one")), two = list(df = structure(list(
    var1_1 = c(1, 1, 1), var1_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), ls = list(n_df_1 = structure(list(var3_1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), var3_2 = c(4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), name = c("two", "two", "two")))
```